# how to support background downloads in iPhone (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, background

I am currently using`**NSURLConnection**`class to download large amount of data (**200MB - 1 GB**). But, my download is getting stopped when the app goes into background.

1-  We cant use ASIHTTPRequest as it was discontinued a long time ago.

2-  I have also seen [Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) documentation by apple. But it only supports background activity for a limited time.

So , here come my question.....

**How can i support uninterrupted background downloads in iOS**

Comment: Here is the doc for threading: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html and you can also look into operation queuing but also remember not to change UI elements from any of these threads, keep those in the main one

Comment: Ah, just realized true background, sorry.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But I'm not 100% sure. Apple only let's you do stuff for another 10 minutes or so after the app is backgrounded.

Comment: i have not tried to go forward with this @Mdroid. To answer your question, NOPE.. :(

Answer (score 0):

on device, it is better to divide data into chunks, it will continue till your server sends data either in background. dynamically generate chunks of fixed size and at the end merge them .

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't used it, https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit says it handles background downloads.